# Why distance is more accurate than angle from translation vector in pose estimation

Tags: matlab, opencv, camera-calibration, pose-estimation

I am using a square (whose size is known) to estimate translation vector between it and the camera. Firstly, the intrinsic camera parameters are calculated, then translation vector (x,y,z) are estimated using 4 points detected from the square.

```
distance = (x^2+y^2+z^2)^1/2
angle = asind(x/distance)
```

I found the estimated distance is accurate even in very far position, while the estimated angle is unstable if the distance is a little far. What's the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: There are better ways of computing angles, `asin` can be unstable in small numbers

Comment: What's the better way to compute angle?

Comment: Depends... Your angle looks a bit weird, why x/distance? you are computing the angles between what and what? For the angle between 2 vectors, the robust way is: `angle = atan2(length(cross_product(a,b)), dot_product(a,b))`